# Changing the VSCode integrated shell's prompt on MacOS X

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, visual-studio-code

Having just installed VScode I have noticed as it uses Bash by default on OSX, with the shell's default prompt of `bash-3.2$`; consequently, I cannot see the current working directory. It means having to type 'pwd' and 'ls' quite frequently which is obvious quite tedious.

I have tried changing the default shell in the settings to

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app"
```

or

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.osx": "/Applications/iTerm.app"
```

This doesn't seem to work, have I made a mistake here?

I would also like to know if I am limited to bash, can I configure it to display the working directory instead of simply `bash-3.2$` ?

See this [screenshot of how the VSCode integrated terminal looks by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxX0U.png)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: (That said, it's easy to modify your prompt to set a PS1 that'll show your directory; see for example http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28739/in-terminal-modify-the-text-that-comes-before)

Comment: ...the standard prompt, showing the hostname and working directory, is `PS1='\h:\W \u\$'` -- if you follow the link, they've got directions for modifying your `~/.bashrc` to control which one is displayed.

Comment: ...actually, waitaminute here. If this is a question about VSCode, rather than the MacOS Terminal, then it's on-topic. Emphasizing that in the title of the question might help. Do you have this problem with the general Terminal app, or *only* with VSCode?

Comment: (...to be clear, if you have the problem only with VSCode, that means that the shell it's launching isn't reading your dotfiles, which gives us an avenue for investigation)

Comment: BTW, one piece of clarification: Terminal **is not a shell**. If you launch a Terminal window, Terminal is then running a separate program -- a shell -- and rendering that program's output and collecting input for it. If VSCode expects `terminal.integrated.shell.osx` to point to a shell, then it needs an actual shell -- something that reads user input from stidn and writes output to stdout -- not something that launches a window and displays output from such a program. By default, that separate shell that Terminal launches is bash.

Comment: ...so the presumptive scenario here is that bash-when-launched-by-vscode is behaving differently from bash-when-launched-by-Terminal. If this presumption is correct -- and clarification would be appreciated -- this is a reasonable and topical question for us to address here.

Comment: Apologies as beyond using the Terminal I am not a bash/shell user. I simply want to see the working directory within the integrated terminal displayed in Visual Studio Code. If I can go about this without having to edit the bash directly that would be preferable. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your prompt to contain the current working directory by defining `PS1` as follows:

```
PS1="\w $"
```

The `$` is just some visual sugar.  There all manner of things you can have your prompt display.  Put the definition in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` for it to be set when you login.

Check out the [Controlling the Prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) section of the GNU Bash manual for details.

If you are not accustomed to editing your `bash` init files you can do it with `Visual Studio Code` by going to `View->Command Palette` and execute the following command (one-time only):

```
Install 'Code' command in path
```

Then open the integrated terminal and type the following:

```
code ~/.bashrc
```

Then add the `PS1` definition to the bottom of that file.

Comment: The question (if it's on-topic, as a question about regular bash configuration would belong on SuperUser or Ask Different) is about changing PS1 in the shell lauched by VSCode. Are you proposing that the OP change the shell in-use manually, or do you have a way to get VSCode (not MacOS Terminal) to automatically use a non-default PS1?

Comment: The question was framed in the context of VSCode, but the problem appeared to be the `bash` prompt.  It could be I am missing something, but his example of changing the default terminal app would not appear to be a solution to the prompt problem where changing the bash prompt would be and his mentioning frequent `pwd` and `ls` commands gave me the impression that he was not `bash` savvy, which is why I responded the way I did.

Comment: They also indicate that they're trying to change their default shell to be Terminal -- disregarding the conflation between shells and terminals, this implies rather strongly that Terminal displays the prompt they way they want it to already, and that the problem is specific to VSCode.

Comment: (...I'm guessing that VSCode isn't invoking bash as a login shell, perhaps, so their `.bash_profile` isn't being executed? Though PS1 configuration rightly belongs in `.bashrc`, so that *shouldn't* make a difference).

Comment: I am a new VSCode user, but when I invoke the integrated terminal I get a login shell with my login prompt and personal aliases, etc.

Comment: sorry but is there not a way to change the default terminal in VScode? 

And to reply to your answer, as a non-bash user how would I go about editing/finding that ~/.bashrc (file I assume?)

Comment: @JamieOMaguire, I amended my answer with the process for editing the `~/.bashrc` file.  FYI, you can put all manner of customization, including command line aliases in that file.  The GNU Bash Manual I cited in the answer is a huge, but well-written resource where you can learn about command line features.

Comment: Happy to help.  If this answers your need, please mark the answer accordingly!

Comment: I know I'm late but check my answer, it's a bash configuration that only affects vscode.

Answer (score 2):

I use Ubuntu, and only add the following lines to the end of `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "vscode" ]; then
  PS1='\$ '
fi
```

Try it and let me know if it works on your OS.

Comment: This suggestion is simply perfect. Once in a VSCode session, one doesn't really need a full blown shell prompt because the session will be probably just a support for whichever project is being done. In my case, I just need a terminal side by side with a console window in order to execute the program being developed and check its returns. Generally, I'm talking about some Python script argument parsing or HTTPServer echoing. It is easy enout to curl -F 'file=@test.json' -X POST localhost:8080 on a terminal and immediately check its return in the console.