# VS Code: Can I hide the directory/location in the terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm new to using VS Code for mac for creating Python scripts. Is there a way to hide the directory of the location of my file when asking my script to print something out? It gets a little confusing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prnHa.png)

I tried looking through the preferences, but there's a huge long list, and am not sure if this doesn't need a terminal command to change the visibility.

Comment: You'd use the normal terminal commands for this; e.g. if in PowerShell `function prompt{'>'}` if in CMD `prompt $G` if in Bash use the PS1 environment variable e.g. `export PS1=">"`, etc.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54368140/how-to-customize-the-shell-prompt-in-the-vs-code-terminal-on-macos

Comment: Hi John, are these commands that get entered into the VS Code terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can install [code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension.

Then add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
  "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
  "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

Then you can use shortcuts "Ctrl+Alt+N" or click **Run Code** button to run the python file.

[image]

[image]